# Not able to integrate Woocommerce to my Custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating Ecommerce (custom Theme) for Worpress site on WP local. Firstly I was getting error when try to install woocommerce, but after downloading plugin and unpacking into my plugins folder plugin installed. but my single product is showing just header and footer and comments box only.

Now I'm trying to update Woocommerce plugin it's showng same error:

Update failed: Could not create directory. woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/assets/js/atomic/blocks/product-elements/add-to-cart/product-types/variable/variation-attributes

Comment: Have you checked your file hierarchy? Can you see all of your folders and files in WP Local and are you sure that directory does not already exist?

Do you have a picture of your file structure so that we can take a look?

Comment: @TheHorstman do you need picture of plugin folder? or theme files?

Comment: A picture of the directory hierarchy that you're trying to update or add the woocommerce plugin/update to.